# Don't firefox have the capability to play the 8k video on Youtube?

Tags: video, youtube

I tried to play 8k video on youtube by using Firefox, but there had not the option to play 8k video. Its have highest 4k option

Comment: Don't run them in the FF browser but choose something like VLC instead.

Comment: It might depend on your hardware. I can see them at 8K (Firefox nightly / Linux desktop). But on an old Android tablet, it goes up to 240.

Comment: This allowed 8k playback: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zCLOJ9j1k2Y with Firefox 70.0...

Comment: when i play it on chrome, it is ok, bt in firefox, it cant play there just